# Validar si un campo no esta vació en Android

Tags: java, validación

Tengo este metodo

```
 public static int Calculate(int N1, int N2, int Operation) {
    int Total = 0;
    switch (Operation) {
        case 0:
            Total = N1 + N2;
            break;
        case 1:
            if(N1 < N2){
                Total = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Total = N1 - N2;
            }
            break;
         case 2:
            Total = N1 * N2;
            break;
         case 3:
             if(N2==0){
                 Total = 0;
             }
             else{
                 Total = N1/N2;
             }
            break;
    }
    return Total;
}
```

Pero si N1 o N2 están vacíos, la aplicación se cerrara.
Como puedo validar si N1 Y N2, no lleguen vacíos?

Answer (score 1):

Los valores integer no pueden ser nulos así que como mucho podrías validar que su valor es > 0.

Answer (score 1):

Para llamar el método `Calculate(int N1, int N2, int Operation)` necesitas enviar valores de tipo entero en los 3 parametros, con respecto a N1 y N2, al tratar de llamar este método no podrás usar valores de tipo cadena (por ejemplo `""`) o `null`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo podrás definir números enteros negativos o positivos.

El problema que puede suceder es una división entre 0 que podrías evitar de esta forma:

```
 public static int Calculate(int N1, int N2, int Operation) {
    int Total = 0;
    switch (Operation) {
        case 0:
            Total = N1 + N2;
            break;
        case 1:
            if(N1 < N2){
                Total = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Total = N1 - N2;
            }
            break;
         case 2:
            Total = N1 * N2;
            break;
         case 3:
             if(N2==0){
                 Total = 0;
             }
             else{
                 if(N2 != 0){  //Validación
                   Total = N1/N2;
                 }else{
                   Total = 0; //Valor en caso de que N sea igual a 0.
                 }
             }
            break;
    }
    return Total;
}
```